# Postgresql query GROUP BY not possible

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

In my project I have this complex query:

```
SELECT FT."Riferimento1", FT."Riferimento2", "CodProdotto", "QuantitaFatturata", "PrezzoUnit", "DataFattura", "NumeroFattura", "CodCli"
FROM public.idocuments_as_fatturetestata FT
LEFT JOIN public.idocuments_as_fatturerighe FR ON FT."Riferimento1" = FR."Riferimento1" AND FT."Riferimento2" = FR."Riferimento2"
WHERE FT."CodCli" = '12192' GROUP BY "NumeroFattura";
```

If I don't use the GROUP BY option all was done but I have to grouping by `NumeroFattura` column.

When I add the Group BY sentence I get this error:

> ERROR:  column "ft.Riferimento1" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

if I add ft.Riferimento1 system ask me ft.Riferimento2 also and all columns, but I want to group  just for NumeroFattura column.

```
"25"    "000006"    "191215002N"    1   1.800000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    589
"25"    "000009"    "112036402G"    100 0.970000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008200I"    200 1.660000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008200N"    150 1.660000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008500V1"   53.5    1.930000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008500E"    61  1.930000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008500R"    56  1.930000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008200G"    50  1.660000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "113066592N"    20  5.583000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "199900502N"    321 0.725000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "199900602N"    360 0.680000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "217001100F"    1200    2.036000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "112031102N"    1200    0.198000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "112044602N"    800 0.600000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "112036402N"    800 0.500000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "113066702N"    800 0.600000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "113066602N"    800 0.550000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "112530780N3"   5000    0.178000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
```

this is an example of output, in the last column i have the NumeroFattura row and i would to group for this value (in this example i should have two rows for results)

Someone can tell me why i can't group like i would?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your current results, and the results that you expect, as tabular text.

Comment: Why a `group by` at all? You are not even using any aggregation functions. Why do you "have to" group by the `NumeroFattura` column? What aggregation are you trying to do?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, what's the problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: You have to write your desired result. Then you can figure it out why you cant group by like that

Comment: What do you expect `GROUP BY` to do with all those different values?

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per `"NumeroFattura"`, then use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("NumeroFattura") FT."Riferimento1", FT."Riferimento2",
       "CodProdotto", "QuantitaFatturata", "PrezzoUnit", "DataFattura",
       "NumeroFattura", "CodCli"
FROM public.idocuments_as_fatturetestata FT LEFT JOIN
     public.idocuments_as_fatturerighe FR
     ON FT."Riferimento1" = FR."Riferimento1" AND 
        FT."Riferimento2" = FR."Riferimento2"
WHERE FT."CodCli" = '12192' 
ORDER BY "NumeroFattura";
```

This returns an arbitrary matching row.  It is unclear *which* row you want, but you can add an additional key to the `ORDER BY` to choose which of them.